# Django. Crispy forms. showing error messages with crispy filter and customizing them

Tags: django, forms, django-crispy-forms

I am new to django forms and Crispy Forms. I have some simple forms in a little forum Im developing. I think I don't need to use the %crispy% tag. I only need the form|crispy filter. However, I don't know why they don't render the error messages.
Also, if I want to customize the error messages (they must be in spanish), do I need to use the %crispy% tag or is it possible to do this with the |crispy filter? 
Anyway, here is one of my forms:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import Textarea

class FormNuevoVideo(forms.Form):
    url = forms.URLField(initial='http://', max_length=250)
    titulo = forms.CharField(max_length=150)
    descripcion = forms.CharField(
        help_text="...",
        widget=Textarea(attrs={'rows': 3, 'data-maxlength': 500}))
```

Here is the view:

```
@login_required
def nuevo_video(request, slug):
    template = 'videos/nuevo.html'
    tema = Temas.objects.get(slug=slug)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FormNuevoVideo(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            ...
            nuevo_video.save()
            return redirect('videos:videos_tema', slug=tema.slug, queryset='recientes')
        else:
            return redirect('videos:nuevo_video', slug=tema.slug)  #this same view.
    else:
        form_nuevo_video = FormNuevoVideo()
        context = {'form_nuevo_video': form_nuevo_video, 'tema': tema}
        return render(request, template, context)
```

And in the HTML:

```
{% block form %}
<form action = "{% url 'videos:nuevo_video' tema.slug %}" method = "post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form_nuevo_video|crispy}}
    <input class = "btn pull-right" type = "submit" value ="enviar"/>
</form>
{% endblock form %}
```

So, lets say, when someone tries to submit a video with a title of more than 150 characters, it doesn't display the error. I am sure I am missing something simple. Also, I'd like to customize the error messages so that they are in spanish. Thanks in advance.